# Prevent character removal / escaping in the message KEY

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf th:text, using the #{} syntax and the message may come from a database message source, with keys containing characters like '+' :

```
th:text="#{${myLabelKey}}"

myLabelKey : stack.overflow.CODE+.label
```

Thymeleaf happen to be removing the '+' character (and I guess other ones), leading to the message not being found.

How can I prevent that ?

Comment: Did you try to use the attribute `th:utext` (for "unescaped text") ?

Comment: I don't want unescaped text, I want unescaped *key*. I knew someone would miread it, that' why i used uppercased letters

Comment: Ok. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: I know this is late. But I have a similar issue. Only thing I came up with replace the special characters with something else. For example replace `+` with `.`.  `${#strings.replace(myLabelKey,'+','.')}` And use `stack.overflow.CODE..label` in messages files.